# Caret package - "Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing"

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm trying to run the following code in R:

`mod_fit <- train(Y ~ X1+X2....+Xn, family = "binomial", data =data,method="glm",trControl=ctrl,tuneLength=5)`

where `ctrl = trainControl(method="repeatedcv",number=10,savePredictions=TRUE)`

But I keep getting the error

```
Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing:
      RMSE        Rsquared  
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :1     NA's   :1    
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : Stopping
In addition: There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Has anyone run into this error before?

Data essentially looks like this:

```
Y      X1     X2   X3   X4

1     10000   0    5    555
0     25000   1    8    999
```

Comment: Show us your data please

Comment: Investigate the warnings. They should tell you something more.

Comment: @ekstroem I can't provide the data itself unfortunately, but data consists of 9 variables, and 900 observations. No non-numeric values, all positive values.

Comment: @114, if they are no non-numeric values, what is Y? This should be a factor of 2 levels, since you're trying to do a logistic regression. Besides you can at least show the structure of the data and maybe a dput of the first 10 rows.

Comment: @phiver Sorry, I misspoke. There is one binary dependent variable as well and the independent variable is binary as well.

Comment: @114, I notice that in your formula you specify family = "binomial" twice. This generates the error on my side.

Comment: @phiver Thanks for pointing that out, I tried it again with that removed and the same error occurred though.

Comment: @114, try adding the warnings to your post. The only way I can create this error in my tests is if Y has more than 2 levels.

Comment: Try to change `data$Y <- factor(data$Y, labels = c("yes", "no"))`. `caret` usually complains if labels are 0 or 1.